# iPod Classic no longer fully syncs via Apple Music app

Tags: data-synchronization, music, apple-music, music.app, ipod-classic

I love my iPod Classics. Alas, I am bummed out because Apple stopped supporting it. My 80GB device still syncs perfectly via the Apple Music app on my 2013 MacBook Pro. The 160GB device does not. It starts syncing, but after a minute, the Mac screen displays the message "Attempting to copy to the disk  failed. The disk could not be read or written to." 8,035 of the 8,287 songs were synced, which is not bad I guess. I created a dynamic playlist in Apple Music containing the last 100 songs added; only 1 song made it over to the same playlist on the 160GB device.

Does anyone have a suggestion to get my 160GB device to sync 100%? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the storage disk is failing

Comment: You could try one last-ditch attempt & reformat it, try again. I had that happen a couple of times, many moons ago, & the device is still working to this day - though it doesn't get a lot of use.